# Variables defined in global scope with identical names

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain, why next js code rises two alert windows with 'string1' text rather than to rise the second with 'undefined' text inside??  If both variables are described in the same scope..

```js
var a = 'string1';  
alert(a);  
var a;  
alert(a);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FdRSZ/1/

Thanks

Comment: Local variables should exibit this same behaviour as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable declarations (and function declarations) are *hoisted* to the top of the scope in which they appear. Assignments happen in place. The code is effectively interpreted like this:

```
var a;
var a;
a = 'string1';
```

For example, consider what happens if you declare a variable inside an `if` statement body:

```
console.log(myVar); //undefined (NOT a reference error)
if (something === somethingElse) {
    var myVar = 10;
}
console.log(myVar); //10
```

Because JavaScript does not have block scope, all declarations in each scope are hoisted to the top of that scope. If you tried to log some variable that was not declared, you would get a reference error. The above example is interpreted like this:

```
var myVar; //Declaration is hoisted
console.log(myVar);
if (something === somethingElse) {
    myVar = 10; //Assignment still happens here
}
console.log(myVar);
```

So even if the condition evaluates to `false`, the `myVar` variable is still accessible. This is the main reason that [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) will tell you to move all declarations to the top of the scope in which they appear.

---

In slightly more detail... this is what the [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) has to say (bold emphasis added):

> For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn d* in *code*, in
>   source text order do
>
> - Let *dn* be the *Identifier* in *d*.
> - Let
>     *varAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env’s* HasBinding concrete
>     method passing *dn* as the argument.
> - **If *varAlreadyDeclared* is `false`, then**
>
>   - Call *env’s* CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and
>       *configurableBindings* as the arguments.
>   - Call *env’s* SetMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn*, `undefined`, and *strict* as the arguments.

So, if a binding already exists with the identifier we are trying to bind now, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

Thats because JavaScript does something called *variable hoisting*. In fact, your JS looks like this:

```
var a; // hoisted -> declared on top

a = 'string1';
alert(a);
alert(a);
```

See [How Good C# Habits can Encourage Bad JavaScript Habits](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-3/) for more details on how JavaScript works.

Comment: Thanks for the link, a useful one

Answer (score 3):

That's because the second `var a` isn't a separate variable declaration. As far as the javascript interpreter is concerned it is the same a as the first one.

Answer (score 3):

`var` means "Scope this variable to this function" not "Set the value of this variable to `undefined`".

If the variable is already scoped to the function then `var foo` means the same as just plain `foo`